# Using the below script i am working on Pagination using Protractor script where is am seeing "summaryPage" is not defined

Tags: protractor

```
this.getPaginationsize = element.all(by.repeater('page in groupArray track by $index'));

summaryPage.getPaginationsize.count().then(function (pagination) {
            if (pagination > 0) {

                for (var i = 0; i < pagination; i++) {
                    summaryPage.getPaginationsize.get(i).click();
                }
            } else {
                console.log('Pagination not exists');
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.getPaginationsize = element.all(by.repeater('page in groupArray track by $index'));

this.getPaginationsize.count().then(function (pagination) {
            if (pagination > 0) {

                for (var i = 0; i < pagination; i++) {
                    summaryPage.getPaginationsize.get(i).click();
                }
            } else {
                console.log('Pagination not exists');
            }
```

you should change it to this as you are referring to the same module you are present in